# Prove that at a point x on the real axis within an analytic domain all the derivatives of f(z) must be real.

Tags: complex-analysis

Background: This is Wunsch Complex Variables with applications 3rd 5.7 problem 17.
I'm including the whole question because I don't know if a hint on part a. will be enough or if I'll still need help on b and c.

[image]

I'm confused about what forced the imaginary part of an analytic function on the x-axis to be zero. If f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y) and it's analytic I would erroneously think that it couldn't have only a real part because $\frac{\partial u(x_0,0)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v(x_0,0)}{\partial y}$.

Comment: That looks wrong to me. I think one needs further condition of $f$. Otherwise, take $D=C$ and any entire function (where in general (a) fails). It looks as if the exercise intends to prove Schwarz's reflection principle, but one also has to assume that $f$ takes real values only on the real axis. (possibly simply forgotton in the book).

Comment: Yes, it makes sense then. $\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{u(x_0+\Delta x)+iv(x_0+\Delta x,0)-u(x_0,0)-iv(x_0,0)}{\Delta x}$ would be real.

Comment: This is wrong. The function $f(z):=i z$ fulfills the given assumptions on ${\mathbb C}$, but $f(\bar z)=i\>\bar z=-\overline{ f(z)}$.